# How to select specific group of row in XL?

Tags: excel, select

I want to select 2,5,8,11,... rows of Excel sheet how can I do that?

can I do that in xl using function or GOTO special?

Comment: In Excel, select row 2 with your cursor; then, holding down **Ctrl**, sequentially select your other desired rows.  But why do you want to select them in the first place? You can't do that with a function -- functions return values.  You can do that with `Goto Special` provided the rows you want have one of the properties described as a possible target for that operation.

Comment: I want to select these series of rows to separate them in another worksheet, your suggested Ctrl and manual selection is expensive, I have over than 10000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a discontinuous group of rows,

- figure out what they have in common
- filter on that characteristic
- If you use the **Advanced Filter**, there's an option to copy results elsewhere.
- If you use the simple filter

  - select the visible range after filter
  - `GoTo Special: Visible cells only`

    - *That will select the unhidden cells*
  - you can now copy/paste.